# IIS displaying folder content list instead of running website (mvc application)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, nopcommerce

can anyone help me. (iis drives me crazy!!)

heres where im at. Ive setup a basic windows server on aws. I used web platform installer to install nopcommerce and dependencies. I first got a 403 error then enabled directory browsing. Now instead of running the site the web browser just displays a list of the contents of the root folder. just a directory listing, instead of starting the webpage.

Answer (score 2):

Disable directory browsing and try.

Answer (score 0):

I got it back up and running by reinstalling the .net framework. Not sure what went wrong but reinstalling seems to have fixed it.